# what is macosxserver in httpd.conf of apache?

Tags: mac-osx, apache-2.2, http

what is the meaning of macosxserver in httpd.conf of apache ?
it is say that  .but what it is ???
when I use websharing ，it works
but I typed sudo apachectl start ,it did not works ,just say not found the document but apache is running .
the documentroot is the same dir ,why it doesn`t not work in the second way ?

*Mac OS X varsion 10.7.2*

Comment: Can you give us any more background about the server/Mac OS X version you are using?